# script working fine but error in console laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysiHtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

here are my footer file that contain links of scripts i have tried 
{!! Html::script('js/test.js') !!}

all these sulution in laravel blade but wrked fine for components but still getting the error message in console of not define.not define .

here i am attaching the blade file as well as console errors i have placed all the files in the 
[layout-blade-php.txt](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/files/997950/layout-blade-php.txt)

public folder

Comment: http://i65.tinypic.com/jzcm0j.png

error pic link in console

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);</script>
```

That line must be placed under your script import statements.

Also your jquery script is commented out. Hope this helps.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysiHtml5.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/js/demo.js"></script>  
    <script> $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);</script>
```